# Can rules within a PMD rule set share common properties?

Tags: java, pmd

I have a PMD ruleset that contains the following rules with properties specified so that I ignore any violations for `equals` and `hashCode` methods automatically generated by Eclipse.

```
<rule ref="rulesets/java/braces.xml/IfStmtsMustUseBraces">
  <properties>
    <property name="violationSuppressXPath" 
              value="//MethodDeclarator[@Image='equals'] | //MethodDeclarator[@Image='hashCode']"/>
  </properties>
</rule>
<rule ref="rulesets/java/braces.xml/WhileLoopsMustUseBraces">
  <properties>
    <property name="violationSuppressXPath" 
              value="//MethodDeclarator[@Image='equals'] | //MethodDeclarator[@Image='hashCode']"/>
  </properties>
</rule>
<rule ref="rulesets/java/braces.xml/IfElseStmtsMustUseBraces">
  <properties>
    <property name="violationSuppressXPath" 
              value="//MethodDeclarator[@Image='equals'] | //MethodDeclarator[@Image='hashCode']"/>
  </properties>
</rule>
<rule ref="rulesets/java/braces.xml/ForLoopsMustUseBraces">
  <properties>
    <property name="violationSuppressXPath" 
              value="//MethodDeclarator[@Image='equals'] | //MethodDeclarator[@Image='hashCode']"/>
  </properties>
</rule>
```

Ideally I would like to share the properties across the rules to avoid duplication. Especially since I plan on adding the same properties for the various cyclomatic complexity rules.

Is there any support for this in a PMD ruleset?

Comment: AFAIK, that is currently not possible. You would have to solve it outside of PMD, e.g. write a script that generates the PMD config file.

Comment: @Thomas that is the conclusion I was coming to. I've opened a ticket https://sourceforge.net/p/pmd/bugs/1466/